# How can I compare a Unix epoch timestamp with a DATE in SQL?

Tags: sql, unix, epoch, oracle18c, sql-date-functions

How can I compare a Unix epoch timestamp with a DATE in SQL?

For example I have a **DATE** *data_type* column with one entry 14-DEC-20 (i.g to_date('14-DEC-20','DD-MON-RR')) and an epoch date equivalent to this. I want to check if the the DATE is equivalent to the epoch, if not then set the equivalent epoch date in the date.

I have tried from_unixtime or with CAST but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert epoch time to a date in Oracle using:

```
date '1970-01-01' + <your epoch value> * interval '1' second
```

You can then use this as a comparison:

```
where datecol = date '1970-01-01' + <your epoch value> * interval '1' second
```

Note:  This does the comparison at the *second* level.  If you want it at the *day* level, you need to adjust.  And you can just use `date` for this:

```
where datecol = date '1970-01-01' + floor(<your epoch value> / (24 * 60 * 60)) * interval '1' day
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work correctly and I cannot understand why. My epoch time is 1626167479458, which actually is: GMT: Tuesday, 13 July 2021 . But after I convert it I get 13-MAR-65.
```select (date '1970-01-01' + floor( 1626167479458 / (24 * 60 * 60)) * interval '1' day) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Changing the calculation actually fixed my issue, thank you ```select (date '1970-01-01' + floor( 1626167479458 / ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * interval '1' day) FROM DUAL;```

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog . . . Formally (eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) Unix time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  However, as you have now encountered, sometimes it refers to the number of milliseconds instead.  The terminology is ambiguous.